# How to hatch Boxplot in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic, boxplot

Can you please tell me how to add **hatching** to a **Boxplot** in `TikZ`? Thanks in advance.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    ylabel={Time (minutes)},
    height=6cm,
    width=6cm,
    ymin=0,ymax=11,
    cycle list={{black},{red}},
    xtick={1,2},
    xticklabels={Phase 1, Phase 2},
    ]
    \addplot+[
    fill,fill opacity=0.2,
    boxplot prepared={
      median=2.59,
      upper quartile=3.35,
      lower quartile=2,
      upper whisker=4.4,
      lower whisker=1.1
    },
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+[
    fill,fill opacity=0.2,
    boxplot prepared={
      median=6.57,
      upper quartile=7.93,
      lower quartile=5.93,
      upper whisker=10.68,
      lower whisker=4.03
    },
    ] coordinates {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was according to the [new manual](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) to add the Hashing pattern description inside the `\addplot+[...]` as following:

[image: Solution]

```
\addplot+[
    pattern={north east lines},pattern color=black,
    boxplot prepared={
      median=2.59,
      upper quartile=3.35,
      lower quartile=2,
      upper whisker=4.4,
      lower whisker=1.1
    },
    ] coordinates {};
```